# Module persists between invocations of the lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, python-import, python-importlib

My AWS lambda handler accepts a code and a unit test for testing that code. Is saves both files in `/tmp`. It calls the following function to load the unit test:

```py
def import_test(name, path):
    module_name = name[:-3]  # Remove the ".py" extension
    imported_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(
        importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, path))
    imported_module.TestCase = TestCase    # TestCase is derived from unittest.TestCase
    imported_module.Messages = Messages
    imported_module.__spec__.loader.exec_module(imported_module)
    test_class = get_test_class(imported_module.__dict__)
    del imported_module
    return test_class
```

Here is the unit test I am testing with (please read the comments in the following code):

```py
import sys
import inspect

from util import foo
del sys.modules['util']        # without this line, the result is same across invocations!

print(inspect.getsource(foo))  # prints correct code even without the above line!

class CodingRoomsUnitTests(TestCase):
    def test_free_fall_time(self, msg='Unit test for foo'):
        self.assertEqual(foo(), 5.0)
```

As the comments state, unless the module is deleted, the unit test always returns the same result for both correct and incorrect `foo`. The results gets updated only when the lambda function is re-deployed.

What's even more strange, is that the `print` statement prints the correct updated source code for `foo`, even though the unit test somehow gets run for a stale version.

This only happens in AWS. In other words, I was not able to reproduce this behavior when testing the lambda handler function locally.

What is going on?

Comment: Your code doesn't actually show a Lambda function handler. Also, are you aware of the notion of cold vs. warm starts in Lambda?

Comment: @jarmod I show only the relevant part to avoid a 160-line listing. I have made the introducing sentences a bit clearer. As for your question, I read posts about resources persisting when they are defined outside of the lambda function. This does not seem to be my case. In any case, how do I cause my lambda function to never use warm starts?

Comment: @jarmod I am using `boto3.client` to invoke the lambda handler from my Django backend.

Comment: You can't control warm/cold starts generally and the Python module loader will cache imports, as you've seen. If you want emulate cold start, you probably want to move your import statements into the function handler and also clear any potentially cached modules.